# Custom appearance for PopupMenu

Tags: gui-construction, customization

### Question

What is the shortest method to make a `PopupMenu` with custom appearance, e.g. something like:

```
wrapper = Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 25] &;
spec = {1 -> "label", 2 -> "label2"};

wrapper @ PopupMenu[Dynamic[test], spec, Appearance -> None]
```

[image]

But the problem here is that only the inner content of the wrapper triggers menu. **`wrapper` needs to be the menu**.

### Problems I've faced

- This won't work as the head of the first argument needs to be `Dynamic`.

  ```
  PopupMenu[ wrapper @ Dynamic[test], spec]
  ```
- This should work but it does not, it seems that unless the first arg of `Dynamic` exactly matches a value it won't be shown.

  ```
  PopupMenu[
    Dynamic[wrapper@test, (test = #) &]
  , spec
  , Appearance -> None
  ]
  ```
- I was about to create something from scratch with DynamicModule and a temporary variable etc, but then I realized I'd have to handle all possible specifications of the second argument of `Dynamic`, `Automatic` 1-2-3 functions etc. (see stress test)

### Requirements

So I'm asking question in hope that I've missed something basic.

The goal is to create `MyCustomPopup` which has custom `wrapper` as an appearance but it also should be ready to replace every `PopupMenu` in my codebase.

Here's a stress test:

```
PopupMenu[Dynamic[test, {Automatic, Print[test]&} ], {1 -> "label"}]

PopupMenu[Dynamic[test, {None, Automatic, Print[test]&} ], {1}]
```

Comment: p.s. AttachedCell won't do because notebook's frame clips it, while native menus can live outside.

Comment: `PopupMenu` can take a fourth argument which does just this. Most custom `PopupMenu`s I've seen use a button with an `Option` based `Appearance` in the fourth argument and set `Appearance->None`

Comment: @b3m2a1 I bet I knew that, well, what are you waiting for?

Comment: No time to write up a good answer now. I'll get to it soon, if no one else does so first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what the 4th argument to `PopupMenu` is for. Here's a quick example:

```
PopupMenu[Dynamic[a],
 {1, 2, 3},
 "asd",
 Button[Dynamic[a],
  Appearance -> 
   FrontEndResource["MUnitExpressions", "ButtonAppearances"],
  ImageSize -> {100, 35}
  ],
 Appearance -> None
 ]
```

[image: example]

Using `Button` for this seems to be the standard thing used internally, based on what I've seen in interface notebooks.

Here's what it looks like clicked:

[image: click]

Note for `ActionMenu` this is often used, too, but the interface element is simply the first argument. I use this all the time. For example here's a screenshot from my basic dev helper palette:

[image: ex2]

Except for that toggle bar, all of this is done using that type of trick, and using `Button` with the `Options` type `Appearance`.